# How to correctly handle data object from REST API using fetch in React

Tags: reactjs, rest, fetch, advanced-custom-fields

I have a React app that receives an object from WordPress site using fetch() over rest api (v2/posts).

The object contains an "acf" entry which holds ~30 sub entries: some arrays and some are objects. All generated with Advanced Custom Field plugin.

The application is updating this data (using this.state) and the server (fetch/post) upon user request. All is working. I am not using express, redux and the like.

My current problem is that I cannot access the internals of the "acf" entry in render() function, while I can access it within the fetch response.
I would like to be able to acccess

```
 cpt['acf']['entry']['subentry']
```

using the entry's names. But I get "cannot access property of undefined..."

Example:

```
        // In constructor:
        //     this.state = {
        //            isLoading: false, title:"", terms:[], cpt: []
        //     }
        ...
                fetch(url)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.ok)
                        return response.json()
                    throw new Error('fetchTerm: Something went wrong ...')
                })
                .then(cpt => {             
                    var terms = Object.entries(cpt['acf'])
                    var title = Object.values(cpt['title'])

                    this.setState({cpt, terms, title, isLoading: false})
    .then( () => {
                console.log("title",this.state.cpt['title'])
                console.log("FAMILYLOG",this.state.cpt['acf']['familylog_array']) // shows ok
            })

                    return (true) // void - no one is looking...
                })
        //...
        render(){
            if (this.state.isLoading)
                    return (Loading)
        // occurs only after fetch resturn and this.state variables are instanciated
            console.log("title", this.state.title) // shows OK
            console.log("FAIL", this.state.cpt['title']) // cannot access property of NULL/Undefined...
            console.log("FAMILYLOG",this.state.cpt['acf']['familylog_array']) // same problem
        }
```

What am I missing?

I would like to be able to acccess `cpt['acf']['entry']['subentry']`

Should I regenerate the cpt into arrays/objects in the Component state?

Comment: Can you update your post to include a console.log of the cpt variable after you put it in state?

Comment: Just added the console.log() in the fetch() call and in render.

Answer (score 0):

according to your code you initialize 
`cpt: []` (which should rather be an object though) in the constructor and then you make a call to the api and only when the promise is resolved you will modify the state, the thing is it happens **after the first render** call is done, so you get "cannot access property of NULL/Undefined" for `cpt['acf']['entry']['subentry']`, though `this.state.cpt['title']` will rather return `undefined` in the `render()`

Upd: To prevent this, isLoading should have been set as true in the constructor

Comment: Please note the isLoading flag that prevents access to this.state prior to fetch() completion.

As for the cpt definition. I did try to set it to an object and got same results

Comment: you might want to set isLoading as true when you assign it for the first time

Comment: You are right! thanks. I set it to true in componentDidMount. Just realized its better in the constructor. thanks

Comment: Great, glad to help!